# Continuity of resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I have to prove continuity of inverse operator.

Let $T$ be an operator on X (a Banach Space), and $\lambda \in C$. Show that $T-\lambda I$ has a continuous inverse (not necessarily defined on the whole space) if and only if there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that

$c||u|| \le ||(T − \lambda I)u||, u \in dom(T)$.

I think that if inverse exists, then $\lambda \in \rho (T)$, so we have to prove that:

$\lambda _n \rightarrow \lambda \Rightarrow R(\lambda _n)-R(\lambda) \rightarrow 0$

$ ||R(\lambda _n)-R(\lambda)||= ||(\lambda _n - \lambda)R(\lambda)R(\lambda _n)||$

Now I'm using inequality.

$||(\lambda _n - \lambda)R(\lambda)R(\lambda _n)|| \le \frac{1}{c}||(T-\lambda I)(\lambda _n -\lambda)R(\lambda)R(\lambda _n)||=\frac{1}{c}||(\lambda _n - \lambda)R(\lambda _n)||$

I don't know if it's all correct and how to find boundedness of $R(\lambda _n)$.

Comment: Is $X$ Banach??

Comment: Yes, I forgot, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following theorem solves the problem:

Let $X$ be a Banach-space, $A \in \mathscr{B}(X)$ (i.e. A is a bounded linear operator). Then the following statements are equivalent:

- A is invertible
- $\text{ran}(A)$ is everywhere dense in $X$ and $\exists C > 0$ so that
  $$\lVert Ax \rVert \geqslant C\lVert x \rVert \quad \forall x \in X$$

The $1 \implies 2$ can be proven with the the fact that $\lVert Ax \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert x \rVert$.

For $2 \implies 1$, we can show that $\text{ran}(A)$ is closed with taking $x \in \overline{\text{ran}(A)}$, and picking a sequence in $X$ so that $Ax_n \to x$. Then we have that
$$\lVert x_n -x_m\rVert\leqslant \frac{1}{C}\lVert Ax_n-Ax_m \rVert$$
which implies that $x_n$ is Cauchy, so $x_n \to x'$ for some $x' \in X$. But the continuity of $A$ implies that $Ax_n \to Ax'$, so $Ax'=x$, so $x \in \text{ran}(A)$.

But $\text{ran}(A)$ is everywhere dense and closed, which implies that $\text{ran}(A)=X$, so $A$ is surjective. And $A$ is also injective, because if we assume that $x\neq x'$, but $Ax=Ax'$, we get a contradiction:
$$0=\lVert A(x'-x)\rVert  \geqslant C \lVert x-x' \rVert \neq 0$$
This implies that $A$ is bijective, so Banach's linear homeomorphism theorem guarantees that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I have a few question. $x_n$ is Cauchy because $Ax_n$ is convergent? 
Shouldn't there be $Ax_n \rightarrow Ax$? What is the submultiplicativity of the operator norm?

Comment: @KrzysztofB $Ax_n$ converges, which means that it's cauchy, so you can make $\lVert Ax_n - Ax_m \rVert$ as small as you want, which means that you can make $\lVert x_n - x_m \rVert$ as small as you want, hence it's Cauchy.

Comment: @KrzysztofB No, $Ax_n \not\to Ax$, because I defined $x$ as $Ax_n \to x$.

Comment: @KrzysztofB the submultiplicative means that for operators A, B, we have that $\lVert AB \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert \lVert B \rVert$, which is not the propery I wanted to refer to. I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Ok, I knew this property, but I didn't hear that name. Thanks a lot. I think that all is clear.

Comment: @KrzysztofB It's the same as the subadditivity, just with multiplication instead of addition. (for example, the norm is subadditive, because of $\lVert x + y \rVert \leqslant \rVert x \lVert + \lVert y \rVert$, but it's usually called triangle inequality).